# Poor I/O performance on EBS optimized r3.xlarge instance with Windows 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, amazon-ebs

I launched a new server with SQL 2012 R2 on a Windows 2012R2 instance sized to r3.xlarge, with EBS-optimized turned on.  I've got three attached EBS drives (GP2), all sized at 1 TB each (3000/IPOS default) and formatted at 64k.  The drives are independent, no RAID at this time.

I/O seems to regularly max out at 50-60 MB/s for all actions - even during sequential file copies of large files between the EBS drives.  Am I wrong to think I should be getting significantly faster speeds?  Anything else to try?

Comment: How many iops are you actually getting? What did AWS support say?

Comment: Haven't contacted AWS support yet, wanted to make sure there wasn't something else I should be doing first.  Ops/s (looking at cloudwatch, 5m, sum) - write seems peak at 1,500/s, highest read sum I saw was 700.  Average queue length hangs out at 30 under load.

Comment: Vendor support should always be your first contact.

Comment: @EEAA that feels like a significant overstatement... vendor support shouldn't be contacted until you have taken reasonable steps to verify that you actually have a reportable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the r3.xlarge instance size has fairly crippled networking, even when EBS-optimized is set to true.  The theoretical limit for an r3.xlarge instance with EBS-optimized is currently 500 Mbp/s or 62.50 MB/s.  So the 50-60 MB/s I am seeing is fairly close to max.  The only additional recommendation was to format for 16k rather than 64k.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html#ebs-optimization-support